# How to set element style property in strict mode?

Tags: javascript, css

Given:

```
body = document.getElementsByTagName('body')[0];
iframe = document.createElement('iframe');
iframe.src = protocol + settings.scriptUrl + a;
iframe.height = 1;
iframe.width = 1;
iframe.scrolling = 'no';
iframe.frameborder = 0;
iframe.style = 'display:none';
body.appendChild(iframe);
```

I see `TypeError: Attempted to assign to readonly property.` on the `iframe.style =` line when testing in Safari, using strict mode.

While it might make sense to require a setter or similar for `.style`, I can't seem to find any information about this being a requirement, and I can also can't find a recommendation for what I should be doing instead.

Some searching lead me to [CSSStyleDeclaration.setProperty()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/CSSStyleDeclaration), which may be what I want, but I'm not sure. And even if that's the right thing to do, I still haven't found any information on either which browsers support this; or how to make sure it works both with/without strict mode and in new/old browsers.

Comment: Try `iframe.style.display = "none";`

Comment: Do not set inline styles at all. Assign a class name and style that one; e.g. `iframe.classList.add('hidden');` and CSS `.hidden { display: none; }`. This will save you some trouble in the long way.

Answer (score 18, accepted):

If you are taking that approach, you need to edit `element.style.cssText` not `element.style`.

From [Mozillas documentation](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/HTMLElement.style):

> Styles can not be set by assigning a string to the (read only) style property, as in elt.style = "color: blue;". This is because the style attribute returns a CSSStyleDeclaration object.

Note that overwriting it will overwrite all the existing inline styles on the element, so you'll generally want to set `element.style.display = "none";` instead.

A better approach, generally, is to modify the classes to which the element belongs and have your styles defined in a separate stylesheet.

Comment: Thanks, I'll give this a try. Do you happen to have a reference explaining the behavior? I'd like to know understand in more detail the thinking around why .style is readonly. Manipulating classes would be a lot better though, that's true.