# Style doesn't working for Disabled element

Tags: html, css, angular, internet-explorer, typescript

Style is not working of we using disabled attribute in text element. Why?

```
<input pInputText [style]="{'padding-bottom':'10px','padding-top':'10px','width':'100%'}"
                       disabled="disabled" [(ngModel)]="selectedApprovalDate" />
```

**It's threw this error**: [*Assignment to read-only properties is not allowed in strict mode*](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36198547/assignment-to-read-only-properties-is-not-allowed-in-strict-mode-in-background)

If I remove the style `[style]="{'padding-bottom':'10px','padding-top':'10px','width':'100%'}"` then it's working. Why?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use `ngStyle` instead

```
<input pInputText [ngStyle]="{'padding-bottom':'10px','padding-top':'10px','width':'100%'}"
                   disabled="disabled" [(ngModel)]="selectedApprovalDate" />
```

Comment: i'll try it. But the same user was answer for the both question :P

Comment: Okay that is the solution. But I want to know why normal style doesn't accept?

Comment: Because the `style` property is `readonly` as the error message says. See also http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24906279/how-to-set-element-style-property-in-strict-mode

Comment: What is normal style? There is no `ngDisabled` in Angular2/4.